# Function call inside a function does not work - PHP

Tags: php

This is simple but I am trying to echo a value from function-1 inside function-2

```
function testing(){
   $files1 = "dir";  
}

function tested() {
    testing();
    echo "testing".$files1;
}
```

Any help on why its not working would be appreciated.

Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45387323/257705

Comment: `$this->testing()`

Comment: @PaulCrovella That possible is accessing one .php file inside another.

Comment: @ArunpandianM there is no indication that he is using an object.

Comment: I second @Paul Crovella, I think it's a scope issue.

Comment: The answer is, you cannot reference a variable that is being declared in another function the way you did.

Comment: @MJoraid ok, I cannot access a variable in another function inside a second function then how do I get it done because that is what I want?

Comment: @PaulCrovella I see some already answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you have to return value from function

```
function testing(){
   $files1 = "dir";  
   return $files1;
}

function tested() {
    $files1 = testing();
    echo "testing".$files1;
}
tested();
```

Answer (score 2):

they function run but the second function doesn't understand the local variable from function one.

I would do the following

```
<?php
function testing(){
   $files1 = "dir"; 
    return $files1;
}

function tested() {
   $files1 =  testing();
    echo "testing".$files1;
}

tested();
?>
```

or you could use the global variable.

```
<?php
function testing(){
   $GLOBALS['files1'] = "dir"; 
   // return $files1;
}

function tested() {
    testing();
    echo "testing ". $GLOBALS['files1'];
}

tested();
?>
```